# NPS: Should I set the measurement to zero for each year or should I accumulate the responses and track the NPS over time?

Tags: measuring, nps

We have two NPS measurement points over the course of a year. 2021 is completed and now 2022 we have completed the first measurement and at the end of the year we will have the second one.
I am creating a detailed report but I am unsure what the best course of action is.
Should I combine this year's responses with last year's and track the NPS over time (how much it increases over the years) or should I set the NPS to zero and let new responses create a new NPS and then compare last year to this year? (Response rate is similar).
I do not want to contaminate the data.

Answer (score 1):

NPS is designed to be a summary of all the contributing factors that might lead to people wanting to recommend the product/service to a trusted person or not. So while it might be a very powerful tool in terms of communicating a trend or key outcome/result, it doesn't do much in terms of helping you hone in on what needs to be addressed.

So depending on the actual purpose of this metric, you could show year-to-year figures that gives an overall sense of where the product/service compares to your competitors (in a benchmarking application), or you can just track the change in NPS for each calendar year (if it makes sense to do so) as a result of all the changes to the customers and the features added to your product/service.